# Pass data from parent swf to child swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two swf, A.swf and B.swf: B.swf is a child of A.swf. Each swf has its DocumentClass. Now: I must pass 4 arrays from A.swf to the DocumentClass of B.swf. Which could be the best way? Is a listener in B.swf a good idea? I noticed there's the possibility to send data over the querystring but I would like to avoid this solution, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not advise starting to walk down the path of Singletons.  Sooner or later, you will regret it. (http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Instead, make the base class of your child swf implement an interface that has a variable for the value you want to set on it.  Once the loader dispatches the complete event, cast your swf to that interface and simply set the variable as normal.

Check out the example here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/example-of-casting-contets-of-swfloader.html.  It's a Flex example, but if you click on the thumbnail, then right click on the movie and select "View Source", you will see the source code.  The source of the Flash movie that implements the Blusher interface is in the flashSrc folder.

HTH;

Amy

Comment: I didn't know the DocumentClass could implement an Interface: I thought I could only extend MovieClip or Sprite.

Comment: Any Class can implement an Interface :-).  Check out the example code.

Comment: Being the technique fairly advanced, I'm not sure I understood. Every swf implements Blusher, so any swf MUST have the variable. On swf load (in your case a library symbol) you cast the children of the main swf to Blusher. Then you access from the main to its inner variable isBlushing and you set its value. Does it work this way?

Comment: Right. When a class implements an Interface, it says "I am guaranteed to have these methods." Unfortunately, you can't have a plain, ordinary variable in an Interface, but you can use a getter/setter pair, which acts the same as a variable. Once the swf is loaded, the main swf will be able to say something like var blusher:Blusher = loader.content as Blusher. if (blusher != null) { blusher.isBlushing = true; } I always check for null, because "is" will give you a null if it is NOT a Blusher. This is just a failsafe in case the wrong swf is loaded.

Comment: Note that the main swf's Class does not need to implement Blusher, just the swf that you're loading in that you need to cast to Blusher (this would be the Class that you'd enter in the Document Class box in the ActionScript Settings).  In my example, the children of the Blusher Flash file can ALSO be cast to Blusher, but I would ignore that part if I were you.  The important part is that the main document Class (BlushingSwf.as) implements Blusher, and therefore the loaded MovieClip itself can be cast to Blusher.  Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Amy,thank you. I haven't tried yet (I'm very tired) but I appreciated your help very much.

Comment: It perfectly works: in the parent swf I changed your code to: var iChild:MovieClip=e.target.content as MovieClip;var blushChild:iBlusher=iChild as iBlusher;blushChild.isBlushing=true. In the iBlusher interface I added a setter. I often ignore interfaces but this is absolutely "clean" and powerful. That is: I could access with e.target.content.isBlushing too, but it's not the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EventListeners solution**

You have some GlobalEventListener ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern ) which is used in both A.swf and B.swf.

You have a customEvent which extends Event and has possibility to send arrays.

```
package com 
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class TransferrArray extends Event 
{
    public static const TRANSFERRING:String = 'transferring';
    private var _array:Array;

    public function TransferrArray(type:String, array:Array, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

        _array = array;         
    }

    public function get array ():Array
    {
        return _array;
    }       
}
```

}

in B.swf somewhere you putting:

```
GlobalEventListener.addEventListener ( TransferrArray.TRANSFERRING, handleTransfer )
private function handleTransfer ( e : TransferrArray) : void
{
    e.array // <- do what you need with it
}
```

in A.swf at the point when your Arrays are ready to be transfered:

```
GlobalEventListener.dispatchEvent ( new TransferrArray ( TransferrArray.TRANSFERRING, [your,arrays,needed,for,b] );
```

**Direct parsing**

B.swf need to have ( the main class of B.swf ) some:

```
public function transferrArrays ( array : Array )
```

in A.swf after B.swf is loaded  and your arrays are ready to be transfered:

```
BSWFLoader.content["transferrArrays"] ( [your,arrays,needed,for,b] );
```

Comment: Jevgenij, I don't understand what GlobalEventListener actually is and what is the method dispatchEventListener (is it a typo for dispatchEvent?)...

Comment: hey, thanx for comment->fixed to dispatchEvent. And GlobalEventListener ir your singletone class which at the end connecting eventDispatcher and eventListener, if they are in a different swf or it can be they are on different levels of movieclips in application.

Comment: Jevgenij, could you provide me with a little sample of the GlobalEventListener class? Only if you have enough time, I don't want to bore you.

Comment: It is just a name of the class i chosed. The class has a variable eventDispatcher. and through this one all event parsing is happening.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i've been programming the last 14 hours and I think it is time to stop.   :-)   Thank you.